# How to use Ajax with specific form

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
        var fname = $("#fname").val();
        var lname = $("#lname").val();
        var mail = $("#mail").val();
        var remail = $("#remail").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var gender = $("#gender").val();
        var dataString = 'fname='+ fname + '&lname=' + lname + '&mail=' + mail + '&remail=' +     remail + '&password=' + password + '&gender=' + gender;

        if(fname=='' || lname=='' || mail=='' || remail=='' || password=='' || gender=='') {
            $('#divMessage').html('Please complete form');
            return false;
        }else{
            $.post('join.php',dataString,function(data){
                $('#divMessage').html(data);
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

If anybody knows how to solve this problem it will be very helpful to me.

```
<form id="signup" name="signup" method="post" action="">
```

I want to use it with specific form not for all forms of page

Comment: Your code is not indented, please fix it.
Also your problem is not clear based on the information that you provided, please give me detail.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using ajax (jQuery post) no form is needed at all, just collect the data and post it to your server. You don't need the form.submit event, just create a button and call your send function:

```
<input type="button" onClick="sendContact();" value="send">

function sendContact() {

    var fname = $("#fname").val();
var lname = $("#lname").val();
var mail = $("#mail").val();
var remail = $("#remail").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var gender = $("#gender").val();
var dataString = 'fname='+ fname + '&lname=' + lname + '&mail=' + mail + '&remail=' + remail + '&password=' + password + '&gender=' + gender;

if(fname=='' || lname=='' || mail=='' || remail=='' || password=='' || gender=='') {
$('#divMessage').html('Please complete form');
    return false;
}else{
    $.post('join.php',dataString,function(data){
        $('#divMessage').html(data);
    });
}
    return false;
}
```

probably brackets are not closed or any other syntax error, this is just an example!

The values concatenated to `dataString` need to be `url-encoded`, consider the user types "A & B Company" as a name?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Axel's answer should work, Also you can bind event directly if you can specified different name to your submit button on that specific form like

```
$("input[name=signup_submit]").click(function() {
```